# Simple Login Page using knockout

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, authentication

I have here a [simple login page](https://jsfiddle.net/ao7b322o/21/) with 1 username, 1 password and 1 login button. What I am doing here is when a user type username and password and if the then click Login button, a function

```
self.login = function(username,password){
  if(password =="default"){
    return isDefaultPassword(true);
  }else{
    return isDefaultPassword(false);
  }
  ko.applyBindings(self.viewModel);
}
```

will be executed, then he will check if the input password is 'default' or not and if yes then I make another `<input type="password" data-bind="visible: isDefaultPassword(true)"` visible, then I should have 1 username input and 2 password input and 1 login button in the login page.

But my question is, why the second password input tag is displayed at the beginning when I load the login page, not after the function `self.login` is executed. And it seems that the `self.login` function can not be called when I click the login button. What did I make wrong here?

Comment: If you add knockout script reference and add $(document).ready(function(){
var newModel = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(newModel);
});  to the end of the scripts you can identify the bugs from there. You can edit this in a couple of ways. One possible solution could be https://jsfiddle.net/egkxq2us/10/

Comment: I will add this comment to answer and you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add knockout script reference and include

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var newModel = new viewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(newModel); 
});
```

to the end of the scripts you can identify the bugs from there.

You can edit this in a couple of ways. One possible solution could be [jsfiddle.net/egkxq2us/10](http://jsfiddle.net/egkxq2us/10)

Which effectively makes isDefaultPassword as an obersvable so that you can toggle the visibility based on that.